# how to test "read-only" input field

Tags: protractor

I'm using Protractor to test an angular application, one of my tests should check if a specific field has a read-only attribute.

```
<input r365-read-only-executive="" class="k-textbox has-full-width ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" type="text" r365-select-on-focus="" id="Prefix" name="prefix" ng-model="prefix" ng-readonly="checked.value == false" readonly="readonly">
```

is there any way to check that ?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [getAttribute()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute) function.

```
var el = element(by.id('Prefix'));  
// or element(by.model('prefix'));
expect(el.getAttribute('readonly')).toEqual('readonly');
```

Comment: @alecxe ah yea, I didn't go through the attributes.  Updated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking the `readonly` attribute, you should check that a user can't type some text:

```js
var input = $('[name=prefix]');  
input.sendKeys("abcd");
expect(input.getAttribute('value')).not.toContain("abcd");
```